# Kafka consumer Not committing offset using reactor-kafka

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, reactor-kafka

I am newbie to Kafka and my kafka consumer is not commiting offset after specified number of messages are consumed.I am trying to do manual commit after consuming every 5 messages using reactor-kafka project.I am verifying my offset commit using lenses consumers UI.

The following are my configurations:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.11</version>
</dependency>





   @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
        public void consumerListener() {
            Properties props = new Properties();
    
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,bootstrapServersUrl);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"consumer-group-1");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG,false);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"latest");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class.getName());
            props.put(ApplicationConstants.SECURITY_PROTOCOL,"SSL");
            props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,"/etc/security/truststore.jks");
            props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG,"Password");
            props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_TYPE_CONFIG,"SSL");
            props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,"/etc/security/keystore.jks");
            props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG,"Password");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,300000);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,300000);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,15000);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,30000);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG,100);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor");
        

 ReceiverOptions<String,String> receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions<String,String>.create(props)                                                             
                               .subscription(Collections.singleton("kafkaprodTopic"))                                                                          
                               .commitBatchSize(5);

    Flux<ReceiverRecord<String,String>> prodFlux = KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions)
                                                       .receive();


                                       prodFlux.subscribe(r ->{
                                            //do business logic
                                            r.receiverOffset().acknowledge();
                                       });
}
```

My consumer is able to consume messages succesfully and I am not seeing any Kafka exceptions as well , only problem is commit offset is not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

you can try - `r.receiverOffset().commit();`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.